Use a planet specific theme to help visually identify different environments in cloud environments
Is it possible to configure a different theme for each planet so that each planet is visually different?
We have had an instance of a user entering training data into our production system and we have been asked to make the training environment visually different.
We currently have a banner in our non-prod planets, but this is not enough.
I have raised a support ticket with Guidewire but they have advised that it is not possible.
Any suggestions?
Screen shot of existing implementation
See previous screenshot for what we have currently.

I have seen carriers using different themes with on-premise InsuranceSuite products. If Guidewire said it is not possible in the cloud then that is probably the final answer.

You can create a new theme, but the each individual user in any environment could change their default theme. There may be a way to set the default theme for every user based on star system, but I am not seeing a way in the documentation. And even if you set the default theme for each user during deployment, someone could change their default theme anyway. I think Guidewire does not support this use case currently.
https://docs.guidewire.com/cloud/pc/202407/config/config/topics/theming/c_changing-visual-style.html
